# how can i look for wallets with a very specific amount of eth?

Tags: wallets, etherscan

I would like to do a sort of a "reverse lookup" of a wallet address. I have the specific quantity of ETH with 18 decimals, and I would like to know what wallet address(es) have this amount of ETH in them. Is this possible? How can I go about looking for this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that you'll need to scrape through blocks to get the highest balance address, it'll take time but it'll be fun.
Install Necessary Packages:

You'll need web3.js, a popular JavaScript library for interacting with Ethereum. Install it with:

npm install web3
//

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

// Connect to an Ethereum node or Infura
const web3 = new Web3('YOUR_ETHEREUM_NODE_URL');

// Define the criteria you're looking for
const desiredBalance = '1000000000000000000'; // 1 ETH in wei

// Fetch transactions
web3.eth.getBlock('latest')
    .then((block) => {
        const blockNumber = block.number;

        // Function to check balance and return addresses with the desired balance
        const checkBalance = async (transaction) => {
            const recipient = transaction.to;
            const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(recipient);

            if (balance === desiredBalance) {
                return recipient;
            }
        };

        // Fetch transactions and check their balances
        const matchingAddresses = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= blockNumber; i++) {
            const blockData = await web3.eth.getBlock(i, true);
            if (blockData && blockData.transactions) {
                for (const tx of blockData.transactions) {
                    const matchingAddress = await checkBalance(tx);
                    if (matchingAddress) {
                        matchingAddresses.push(matchingAddress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        console.log('Matching addresses:', matchingAddresses);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

Also you can check:- [Ethereum account records](https://etherscan.io/accounts)